# Convergence in probability of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-expectation, random, filtrations

Suppose I have a sequence of random variables $X_n$ and $\sigma$-fields $\mathcal{F_n} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_n'$. Suppose that $\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n']$ converges to a constant $c$ in probability. Does it follow that $\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$ also converges to $c$ in probability? It seems the answer should be "yes" since $\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$ is "less random" than $\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n']$, but I can't prove this.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think that the convergence in probability implies the convergence of $$\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n') \, d\mathbb{P}$$ to $0$? This claim seems pretty odd to me, in several regards...

Comment: Ah you're right, that is nonsense.

Comment: Wait bigger sigma algebra is the less random one right? @saz, is the Converse perhaps true? Or true a.s.? Or true for most but some cases?

Comment: I don't think that there is a reasonable converse. You would need to define "most but some" ...

Comment: @saz I wanted to keep it imprecise. I like 'reasonable converse' better.

Comment: @BCLC Yeah, obviously; it's the easiest thing for you to keep things imprecise. As I already told you, I don't think that there is a reasonable converse. Since the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_n$ contains less information than the bigger one, there is no reason why the convergence of $\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n)$ should imply the convergence of $\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n')$. The trivial counterexample is $\mathcal{F}_n := \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ which gives you no information except than the convergence of the expectation value of $X_n$.

Comment: @saz Thanks. I didn't expect a reply actually. So, thanks all the more. Anyhoo, I made a generalisation: [Convergence of $\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n']$ if or only if $\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806378)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the assertion does in general not hold true.
Consider, for instance, a sequence of independent random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that

$$\mathbb{P}(X_n = -n^2+1) = \frac{1}{n^2} \qquad \mathbb{P}(X_n=1) = 1- \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

It follows easily from the Borel-Cantelli lemma that $X_n \to 1$ almost surely (hence in probability). On the other hand, a straight-forward computation shows $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=0$ for all $n \geq 1$. If we define

$$\mathcal{F}_n := \{\emptyset,\Omega\} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathcal{F}_n' := \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$$

this means that

$$\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \to 0 \quad \text{but} \quad \mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n') \to 1.$$

Comment: saz, do you know the relation with [constructing a zero-mean martingale →−∞ a.s.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2796856) please?

Comment: @BCLC What makes you believe that there is a connection between the two problems...?

Comment: saz, it seems similar. There, $X_n \to -1$. Instead of $2^n$, but we still have $n^2$ where $$\sum \frac{1}{2^n}, \sum \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$$

Comment: @BCLC Ah you mean the example which I gave in my answer... yeah, it's essentialle the same as in the question you linked.

Comment: @saz thanks! ^-^

Comment: Saz, how is Xn Fn-measurable please?

Comment: @BCLC It's not, but I don't think that the OP wants to assume that $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. Is $X_n$ was $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, then $X_n$ would be also $\mathcal{F}_n'$-measurale and therefore $$\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n) = X_n = \mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n')$$ In that case, we clearly have that the left-hand side converges (in probab./a.s.) iff the right-hand side converges (in probab./a.s.)

Comment: @saz You're right, I did not want to assume $X_n$ was $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Since $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, $X_n$ is also $\mathcal{F}_n'$-measurable. Therefore, $$\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n) = X_n = \mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n')$$

LHS conv in any mode iff RHS conv in the same mode.

Source: saz comment in reply to my noticing that saz' Xn is not saz' Fn-measurable

Comment: saz was correct, I do not want to assume $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. That was a typo.