# constructing a zero-mean martingale $\to -\infty$ a.s.

Tags: limits, probability-theory, martingales, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I'm reading a book over martingale theory and there is a exercise where I'm interested in a solution.

Let $X_{1},X_{2},...$ be independent random variables with

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = -1) &= 1 - 2^{-n}\\
\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 2^{n} - 1) &= \frac{1}{2^{n}}
\end{align}
Now the task is to construct with thiss sequence a martingale $Y_{n}$ with $\mathbb{E}(Y_{n}) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} Y_{n} = -\infty$ alsmost surely.

Comment: Try to apply Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: @clark I posted an answer. Is it right please?

Comment: Look what I found: [Convergence in probability of conditional expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2785274/convergence-in-probability-of-conditional-expectation). Related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum martingale $$Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$$

Check:

1. $$E[Y_n]=E[X_n]=0$$
2. $$\lim Y_n = -\infty \ a.s. \ \because \lim X_n = -1 \ a.s. \ (\text{Check with Borel-Cantelli Lemmas!}) (*) $$
3. $Y_n$ is integrable, adapted to $\mathscr F_n = \mathscr F_n^X := \sigma(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ and $\forall m < n,$ $$E[Y_n | \mathscr F_m]=E[\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i | \mathscr F_m]=\sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i + E[\sum_{i=m+1}^{n} X_i | \mathscr F_m]=\sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i + E[\sum_{i=m+1}^{n} X_i]=\sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i = Y_m$$

---

(*)

Pf: By BCL1 & BCL2, we have

$$P(\liminf (X_n = -1))=1$$

$$P(\limsup (X_n = -1))=1$$

The latter is of course redundant. The former by itself gives us only, for now. $P(\lim A_n) = \lim P(A_n) = 1$ where $A_n = (X_n = -1)$. Now, by contrapositive of important inequalities (ii) and (iv) (**), we have, resp,

$$\limsup X_n \le -1$$

$$\liminf X_n \ge -1$$

QED

---

(**)

Important inequalities

Williams - Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

Deduced similarly:

(iii) If $\liminf x_n > z$, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n > z)$ eventually (that is, for infinitely many n)

(iv) If $\liminf x_n < z $, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n < z)$ infinitely often (that is, for infinitely many n)

Comment: Why does $$\mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n=-1\right)=1$$ imply that
$$\mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n=-\infty\right)=1\quad \large\mathsf ?$$

Comment: Looks good(+1).

Comment: @clark Thanks ^-^

Comment: @Math1000 $\sum (-1) = -\infty ?$

Comment: nice answer. Very good! (:

Comment: @love_math thanks! Good to know all answer attempts, mostly met with tough but fair criticism on pretty much mostly bad answers finally paid off with a nice answer.

Comment: @love_math accept answer?

Comment: can you please show why $\lim X_{n} = -1$ almost surely? Then I will accept the answer. Intuitevely it is clear for me, but how to write it formally?

Comment: @love_math Done

Comment: I have prove it this way: We have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_{n} \neq -1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}} < \infty$. Therefore with Borell Cantelli we have $\mathbb{P}(\lim \inf \{X_{n} = -1\}) = 1$ and this implies also that  $\mathbb{P}(\lim \sup \{X_{n} = -1\}) = 1$

Comment: @love_math it's the first part of what I did. It is sufficient but needs justification, at your level of learning, to conclude Xn=-1 a.s. the justification is in the important inequalities

Comment: but it is correct what I did?

Comment: @love_math depends on your level of learning. If you're beginning, definitely you wouldn't get full marks.

Comment: I don't understand what are you meaning? My approach is also correct since $\lim \inf A_{n} \subset \lim \sup A_{n}$

Comment: @love_math your approach is incomplete. Lim (Xn = - 1) is not the same as (Lim Xn) = - 1

Comment: What I show now is $\mathbb{P}(\lim X_{n} = -1) = 1$ or not?

Comment: this conversation is quite interesting. Thanks for your effort (:. I want to understand, why my approach is not correct. My question is: if $\mathbb{P}(\lim \inf A_{n}) = \mathbb{P}(\lim \sup A_{n}) = 1$ can I deduce that $\mathbb{P}(\lim A_{n}) = 1$

Comment: @love_math you deduced Lim (Xn = - 1) not (yet) (Lim Xn) = - 1. P(lim An) = 1 is the former not the latter.

Comment: Now I show that $\mathbb{P}(\lim \inf X_{n} = -1) = 1$ Therefore I can deduce that $\lim \inf X_{n} \geq -1$ a.s. Furthermore I have show $\mathbb{P}(\lim \sup X_{n} = -1) = 1$, therefore $\lim \sup X_{n} \leq -1$ a.s. Therefore I have $\lim \sup X_{n} \leq \lim \inf X_{n}$ and now I can deduce that $\lim X_{n} = -1$ a.s. Correct?

Comment: @love_math yeah.just remember, the justification for those probabilities is the contrapositive of the important inequalities.